# Chef Deployment Failure: CreateProcessW() Error

Tags: ruby, winapi, rubygems, chef-infra, chef-recipe

### Issue

I run Chef Client on approximately 40 machines a day. Over the past couple of months we have came across Chef failures having to do with, "CreateProcessW - Invalid Access to Memory Location". These failures are extremely difficult to replicate but come up at least a couple times a week on completely random recipes.

I am currently running Chef Client 12.6 and have been seeing these issues on both Windows 10 & Windows 7 operating systems. An example Chef recipe in which a failure occurred along with its stacktrace below. I was wondering if anyone has run into any related issues dealing with CreateProcessW() failures and if so, have you found a viable solution?

Thanks.

### Failed Chef Recipe Example

```
package 'Octopus Tentacle' do
    action :install
    source "#{node['octopus']['url']}"
    installer_type :msi
    options '/qn /norestart'
end
```

### Stacktrace

```
windows_package[Octopus Tentacle] (ims_server_prereqs::octopus_tentacle line 13) had an error: SystemCallError: Invalid access to memory location. - CreateProcessW
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.2.5-universal-mingw32/lib/mixlib/shellout/windows/core_ext.rb:347:in `create'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.2.5-universal-mingw32/lib/mixlib/shellout/windows.rb:80:in `run_command'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.2.5-universal-mingw32/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:259:in `run_command'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/mixin/shell_out.rb:97:in `shell_out_command'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/mixin/shell_out.rb:50:in `shell_out'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/mixin/shell_out.rb:55:in `shell_out!'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider/package/windows/msi.rb:70:in `install_package'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider/package/windows.rb:132:in `install_package'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:100:in `block (2 levels) in action_install'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:226:in `multipackage_api_adapter'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:99:in `block in action_install'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `call'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider.rb:175:in `converge_by'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:98:in `action_install'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider/package/windows.rb:126:in `action_install'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/provider.rb:144:in `run_action'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/resource.rb:596:in `run_action'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/runner.rb:74:in `run_action'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/runner.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/runner.rb:106:in `each'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/runner.rb:106:in `block in converge'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:83:in `block in execute_each_resource'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:81:in `execute_each_resource'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/runner.rb:105:in `converge'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/client.rb:658:in `block in converge'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/client.rb:653:in `catch'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/client.rb:653:in `converge'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/client.rb:692:in `converge_and_save'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/client.rb:271:in `run'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/application.rb:243:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/application.rb:220:in `block in run_chef_client'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/application.rb:203:in `run_chef_client'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/application/client.rb:413:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/application/client.rb:403:in `loop'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/application/client.rb:403:in `interval_run_chef_client'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/application/client.rb:393:in `run_application'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/application.rb:58:in `run'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0-universal-mingw32/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client:64:in `load'
C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client:64:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Chef 12.13 or newer. There was an issue for a while where mixlib-shellout would, rarely, try to kill the console executor process which does some really bad things. In general if reporting a bug, try using a recent version. There are 6+ months of fixes and no one is going to sit down and figure out if one of those is the one you need.